# python gtk 3.0 whether Accessing GUI from secondary thread is not supported?

Tags: python, gtk3

I developed a GUI program based on python Gtk3. In the Main Window there is a button and a progressbar, my purpose is when pressing the button there is another thread running to do some work finally another GTK window shows up to display the result, in the meantime the preogress could update the progress in the main Window correctly.

But I always got a error as below:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I really don't know what is going wrong there and have no idea about it, could anyone help taking look at it and provide a example here ?

Thanks a lot !

I developed a test program here as below, I always got the follow errors under Linux platform:
(fileChooser.py:40834): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_text_attributes_ref: assertion 'values != NULL' failed

(fileChooser.py:40834): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_text_attributes_ref: assertion 'values != NULL' failed

(fileChooser.py:40834): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import re
import multiprocessing
import threading
import platform
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, Gdk, GObject

class ANA(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)                                                                                                                                                              
        self.tree_store = dict()
        self.COL_NAME = 0 
        self.COL_COLOR = 1 

        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_title("Analysing Results")
        self.window.set_size_request(1000, 750)
        self.connect('destroy', lambda *w: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.main_vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=1)
        self.window.add(self.main_vbox)

        self.hpaned = Gtk.HPaned()
        self.hpaned.set_position(295)
        self.main_vbox.pack_start(self.hpaned, True, True, 0)

        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        for tab in ['A', 'B']:
            scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
            scrolled_window.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
            scrolled_window.set_shadow_type(Gtk.ShadowType.IN)

            self._new_notebook_page(self.notebook, scrolled_window, tab)

            treeview = self.__create_treeview(tab)
            scrolled_window.add(treeview)

        self.hpaned.add(self.notebook)

        self.notebook1 = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.hpaned.add(self.notebook1)
    
        self.scrolled_window2, self.info_buffer, self.info_text_view = self.__create_text(True)
        self._new_notebook_page(self.notebook1, self.scrolled_window2, '_Info')

        info_text_view = self.info_text_view

        self.window.show_all()

    def _new_notebook_page(self, notebook, widget, label):
        l = Gtk.Label(label='')
        l.set_text_with_mnemonic(label)
        notebook.append_page(widget, l)

    def __create_text(self, is_source=False):
        scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled_window.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        scrolled_window.set_shadow_type(Gtk.ShadowType.IN)

        text_view = Gtk.TextView()
        scrolled_window.add(text_view)

        buffer = Gtk.TextBuffer()
        text_view.set_buffer(buffer)
        text_view.set_editable(False)
        text_view.set_cursor_visible(True)

        return scrolled_window, buffer, text_view
        
    def __create_treeview(self, tab_name):
        treestore = Gtk.TreeStore(str, str)
        self.tree_store[tab_name] = treestore
        treeview = Gtk.TreeView(treestore)
        selection = treeview.get_selection()
        selection.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.BROWSE)
        treeview.set_size_request(200, -1) 

        cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(tab_name, cell, foreground=self.COL_COLOR)
        column.add_attribute(cell, "text", self.COL_NAME)

        treeview.append_column(column)

        if tab_name == "A":
            selection.connect('changed', self.selection_changed_A)
        elif tab_name == "B":
            selection.connect('changed', self.selection_changed_B)

        treeview.expand_all()
        return treeview

    def selection_changed_A(self):
        print "A" 

    def selection_changed_B(self):
        print "B" 

class ANALYSING_PROCESS(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ANALYSING_PROCESS, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        ANA()

class ANALYSING_THREAD(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, pbar, timer):
        super(ANALYSING_THREAD, self).__init__()
        self.pbar = pbar
        self.timer = timer

    def run(self):
        Gdk.threads_init()
        Gdk.threads_enter()
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        ANA()
        Gdk.threads_leave()

        self.pbar.set_text("Done")
        self.pbar.set_show_text(True)
        GObject.source_remove(self.timer)

class File_Chooser(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect('destroy', lambda *w: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.set_title("Test")
        self.set_border_width(8)

        frame = Gtk.Frame()
        self.add(frame)

        self.vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=8)
        self.vbox.set_border_width(8)
        frame.add(self.vbox)

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<span font_desc=\"Serif 25\" foreground=\"#015F85\" size=\"x-large\"> Test</span>")
        self.vbox.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)

        self.button_entry = dict()
        self.entry_name = dict()

        hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=8)

        button = Gtk.Button("Browse Files")
        button.connect('clicked', self.browse_files)
        hbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<span foreground=\"#015F85\"> files </span>")
        label.set_use_underline(True)
        hbox.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)

        self.entry1 = Gtk.Entry()
        hbox.pack_start(self.entry1, True, True, 0)
        label.set_mnemonic_widget(self.entry1)
        self.button_entry[button] = self.entry1
        self.entry_name['files'] = self.entry1

        self.vbox.pack_start(hbox, False, False, 0)

        separator = Gtk.HSeparator()
        self.vbox.pack_start(separator, False, False, 1)

        alignment1 = Gtk.Alignment()
        alignment1.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.vbox.pack_start(alignment1, False, False, 1)

        self.pbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        alignment1.add(self.pbar)
        self.pbar.set_text("Not Run")
        self.pbar.set_show_text(True)


        hbox2 = Gtk.HBox(False, 2)
        self.vbox.pack_start(hbox2, False, False, 1)

        button3 = Gtk.Button("Analyze")
        button3.connect('clicked', self.tar_File_analyze)
        hbox2.pack_end(button3, False, False, 1)

        button4 = Gtk.Button("close")
        button4.connect('clicked', self.__quit)
        hbox2.pack_end(button4, False, False, 1)

        self.show_all()

    def browse_files(self, button):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        filter = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter.set_name("Tar files")
        filter.add_pattern("*.tar")
        filter.add_pattern("*.rar")
        filter.add_pattern("*.tar.gz")
        dialog.add_filter(filter)

        filter = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter.set_name("All files")
        filter.add_pattern("*")
        dialog.add_filter(filter)

        filter = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter.set_name("Images")
        filter.add_mime_type("image/png")
        filter.add_mime_type("image/jpeg")
        filter.add_mime_type("image/gif")
        filter.add_pattern("*.png")
        filter.add_pattern("*.jpg")
        filter.add_pattern("*.gif")
        filter.add_pattern("*.tif")
        filter.add_pattern("*.xpm")
        dialog.add_filter(filter)

        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print dialog.get_filename(), 'selected'
            self.button_entry[button].set_text(dialog.get_filename())
            #entry.set_text(dialog.get_filename())
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print 'Closed, no files selected'
        dialog.destroy()

    def tar_File_analyze(self, button):
            
        #PROGRESS_THREAD(self.pbar).start()
        self.pbar.set_text("Running")
        self.pbar.set_show_text(True)
        ####self.timer = GObject.timeout_add (100, self.progress_timeout, self)
        self.timer = GLib.timeout_add(100, self.progress_timeout)
            
        t = ANALYSING_THREAD(self.pbar, self.timer)
        #t = ANALYSING_PROCESS()
        t.start()

    def progress_timeout(self):
        self.pbar.pulse()
        return True

    def warning(self, warnings):
        dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(self, 0, Gtk.MessageType.WARNING,
                Gtk.ButtonsType.OK, "Warning!")
        dialog.format_secondary_text(warnings)

        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            dialog.destroy()

    def __quit(self, button):
        self.destroy()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()

def main():
    File_Chooser().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Could anyone take a look at it ?

Comment: Please include example code that produces the error.

Comment: Did you have a look here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading ? This describes the canonical way to access the main loop from another thread. That said, I myself had problems with Gtk an multi-threading because I missed that idle_add somewhere, but I never got such an xcb failure. So, not sure it is related to Gtk, maybe rather another part of your code.

Comment: I checked it before, but sill not work

Comment: @DanD. I added the example code, could you help take a look at it ? Thanks !

Comment: @DanD. Any comments here ?

Answer (score 3):

In general, GUI toolkits do *not* support multiple threads making toolkit calls. Usually only the initial thread is allowed to do that. Making a GUI toolkit really thread-safe is a hard problem and this is a way to avoid it.

A possible solution is to have the main thread use an idle function or timer callback to check the progress in the worker thread.

Another solution is to to the work in an external *process* instead of a *thread*. This has a number of advantages;

- It makes communication explicit and tracable. GUI toolkits can generally watch e.g. a file descriptor or a socket, processing the info from it in a timeout or idle callback.
- Keeping the GUI single-threaded makes locking mostly unnecessary.
- And on CPython it can actually make use of multi-core machines by side-stepping the GIL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to do the work in an external process instead of a thread, but always get a Gdk Warnings and fail, It works properly in gtk2, but in gtk3 it doesn't.  Do you have any examples for it ?

Comment: I also tried to use an idle function or timer callback in the main thread to check the progress, but when press the button, the progress bar never updated, after work thread finished displaying a new Window, the progress bar starts updating.

Comment: I've not written programs in gtk+3 yet.

Comment: I added the example here in gtk 3. @Roland Smith

Comment: Any comments here ?  @Roland Smith

Comment: Try running the program under a Python debugger so see where the errors are happening. At a *guess* I would say somehere in `__create_text`, because the error pertains to text attributes.